# Java double and bigdecimal same weird value

Tags: java

I'm making a calculation module about that accepts `double` or `BigDecimal` like this but I have this problem.

```
double x = 2.3333333333312398;
BigDecimal big = BigDecimal.valueOf(2.3333333333312398);
```

I print their values

```
System.out.println(x);
System.out.println(big);
```

and the output

```
2.3333333333312396
2.3333333333312396
```

I tried to changed the value of `x` and `big` variable to `2.3333333333312395`
but the output still the same. I changed it again to `2.3333333333312396` and prints the same value.

If I changed again to `2.3333333333312394` the displayed again the weird value

`2.3333333333312396`

What's the cause of this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're running up against double's limits to accuracy since you're initializing your BigDecimal with a double literal. Instead, consider initializing your BigDecimal with a String literal, not a double literal value:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  double x = 2.3333333333312398;
  BigDecimal big = BigDecimal.valueOf(2.3333333333312398);
  BigDecimal big2 = new BigDecimal("2.3333333333312398");

  System.out.println(x);
  System.out.println(big);

  System.out.println(big2);
}
```

which returns:

```
2.3333333333312396
2.3333333333312396
2.3333333333312398
```

Answer (score 2):

```
double x = 2.3333333333312398;
```

The problem is here. Doubles don't have 17 decimal digits of precision, only in fact about 15.9. Same applies when you use that constant in BigDecimal.valueOf(). In fact it has already been truncated by the compiler. You can't get the result you want out of a double at all, but you can with BigDecimal if you construct it with that value in a string literal.